# OpenLayers 3, static tiles and XYZ coordinates

Tags: openlayers-3

The goal is to be able to zoom onto a high-res picture (11520x11520) that I have split into 256x256 squares. I took the large image and resized it to 80%, 60%, 40%, 20% and 8.89%. Then, for each of the images from 100% to 8.89%, I split them. It's to make an interactive video game map like this: http://www.ark-survival.net/en/dynamic-livemap/

I have tried this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'ark_map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'images/map/{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png',
                tileSize: 256,
                maxZoom: 5
            })
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [50, 50],
        zoom: 5,
        minZoom: 0
    })
});
```

The result: I only see the top left corner on any zoom used. I've seen many examples and many questions, but combining static tiles and XYZ (on pixels) has never come up.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magikweb/6moqu7q8/3/).

How do you combine static tiles and XYZ coordinates based on a pixel system?

Comment: Did you see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/6f233kLy/)?

Comment: I added the JS Fiddle to show you what it does on my end.

Comment: By the way, what did you use to split the image?

Comment: I used TileMage image Splitter. (http://tilemage.50webs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very weird tile layout. What you describe maps to this set of resolutions:

```
var resolutions = [
  45/4,
  45/4/2*0.889,
  45/4/4*0.889,
  45/4/6*0.889,
  45/4/8*0.889
];
```

With that, you can configure an `ol.tilegrid.TileGrid`:

```
new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
  origin: [0, 11520],
  resolutions: resolutions
})
```

See updated fiddle for the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/6moqu7q8/4/.

Comment: Could you explain what element is weird and how you figured out the resolution array you've made? It seems a little glitchy at times, could it be that the zooming has to follow certain guidelines I haven't followed properly?

Comment: Usually, a tile grid starts with one tile at zoom level zero, and then always divides one tile into four tiles for the next zoom level. Fortunately, OpenLayers supports arbitrary grid configurations like yours just fine. Actually I figured out your resolutions by combining trial and error with the information you provided.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by glitchy, but to get crisper images, you'll need to have the same view resolutions as your source. This can easily be achieved by passing the same resolutions array to the view configuration. The downside is that you won't be able to view your whole world, unless you add more resolutions for the view. See https://jsfiddle.net/6moqu7q8/5/ for an updated fiddle.